# FontAwesome Icons not working properly in react/next app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

Solved - TLDR; Adding `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'` to the _app.js / index.js file fixes the issue and FontAwesome works as intended. My issue was caused by `npx-create-next-app` including purgeCSS by default, which in turn stripped out the FontAwesome required styles.

---

I'm using FontAwesome in my Next app. I followed the [React guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react) on the FA website and the icon SVG's are being output on the page. Problem is, none of the [features](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react#features) work and they don't scale with font-size as they're meant to.

I don't want to hack it together by manually targeting the SVG's and adding size etc. as it's not ideal when it comes to responsiveness. i.e. it would be nice to have icons scale with accompanying text and the ability to add 'spinner', 'fixedWidth' etc.

Strangely, they have started working once or twice but then break again and I can't seem to reproduce.

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
  }
```

```
// _app.js
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
library.add( faHeart )
```

```
// header.js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default function Header() {

  return (
    <header>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['far', 'heart']} spin />
    </header>
  )
}
```

```
// style.css
header {
 font-size: 20px; (does nothing to the icon)
}

svg {
 width: 20px; (works, but this shouldn't be required according to FA docs)
}
```

I've also tried individual use (importing icons into individual components, rather than utilising the library function) to the same effect. Like so:

```
// header.js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'

export default function Header() {

  return (
    <header>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} spin />
    </header>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Fixed it. The issue was purgeCSS which was added to the project when using `npx-create-next-app`. purgeCSS was purging the required FontAwesome styles.

Explicitly importing the FontAwesome styles fixed the issue.

Specifically, I added `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'` to _app.js.

Comment: How does one do this when using the CDN/fontawesome kits?

Answer (score 5):

According to the doc, The react-fontawesome component integrates well with Next.js but there is one caveat you need to solve. Since Next.js manages CSS differently

In your project entry, probably App.js

```
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false
```

Next.js allows you to import CSS directly in .js files. It handles optimization and all the necessary Webpack configuration to make this work.

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
```

You change this configuration value to false so that the Font Awesome core SVG library will not try and insert  elements into the  of the page. Next.js blocks this from happening anyway so you might as well not even try.

```
config.autoAddCss = false
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the three lines to `_app.js` you mentioned solved my problem.

Comment: Adding first 3 lines of code to root `layout.tsx` file worked in next@13.4

Answer (score 1):

I use FontAwesomeIcon in my React apps like this and it works:

```
import { faHeart} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

in the code:

<FontAwesomeIcon  className="icon" icon={faHeart} />
```

and in css:

```
.icon{
color: ; / if you want to change color
font-size: 36px;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the global method in order to simplify things. I've tried this per-component method of importing icons too but they still don't scale with font-size and none of the options work. I can of course target the icons with classes but I'm trying to get it to work the way it's intended to work and allowing me to use the built in features such as `fixedWidth` and `size="lg"`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, all you need to do is:

import the icon:

```js
import { yourIcon} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

and use it:

```js
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={yourIcon} />
```

You can add a classname to the icon and use that class to style it.

```js
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={yourIcon} className="styled-icon" />
```

Here is a good video on adding font awesome icons to next.js: https://youtu.be/kaA2aX4X3NU

Comment: My issue isn't getting the icons to load or anything, that bit's working fine. The issue is that they aren't working as intended. None of the FA features work and the icons don't inherit size from font-size like they're meant to. I want to get them working the way FA intended which is much better for things like responsiveness. i.e. an icon that accompanies text can scale alongside the text automatically, rather than individually creating media queries for each.